When we are on the ground do we still accelerate with 9.8 m/s²?
Do we accelerate with 9.8 m/s² when we are on the ground , if so why we do not fall inside the eart . How is the net force is zero , how many real forces acts on the body ?

Does this answer your question? How can you accelerate without moving?
